# pointer to char array, unhandled exception

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I'm new to C++ and I'm playing with pointers. I can't figure out why this piece of code doesn't work for me. Can you tell me what's wrong with it?

```
char * name = "dharman";
char *ptr = name+3;
*ptr = 'a';

printf("%s", name);
```

I get unhandled exception all the time.

Comment: You should enable compiler warnings - they can be very useful for finding mistakes, including this one. Even if your compiler is outdated enough to allow this dodgy conversion, it should still give a warning about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This alone is an error:

```
char * name = "dharman";
```

The string is in constant memory but the pointer's type indicates it can be modified. Attempting to modify it produces undefined behavior: on other platforms the program will work but you got unlucky.

This was a quirk in C++03; the newer C++11 spec makes it illegal. The reason it was ever done was C compatibility.

Whether you're writing in C++ or plain C, the solution is simple:

```
char name[] = "dharman";
```

Now the compiler stores the data in read-write memory because you have asked for an array of `char`, not a pointer to some other memory.

Answer (score 1):

String literals, like `"dharman"`, are read-only and you cannot modify them. Instead, create and  initialize an array that is not read only.

```
char name[] = "dharman";
```

Answer (score 1):

`name` is a pointer to a string literal `"dharman"`, which is located in read-only memory.
In your statement `*ptr = 'a'`, you are trying to modify this string literal, which results in `Undefined Behavior`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `"dharman"` is constant, it's a string literal. You cannont change it!

String literals are usually placed in read-only segments of memory.

Comment: How come it's constant, I didn't declare it as a constant.

Comment: @Dharman: String literals are constant - that's just how the language works.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to modify a constant string.
You need to copy the constant first to some memory that you own.
Try this:

```
char *name = (char*) malloc(10);
memcpy(name, "dharman", strlen("dharman"));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `name` to point at a `const` string and then trying to modify it.  Copy the string to a modifiable location:

```
char *name = (char*) malloc(strlen("dharman") + 1);
memcpy("dharman", name, strlen("dharman") + 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason for unhandled exception in your case is.In your code

```
char *ptr= name+3;
```

consider the base address of name as eg:23300, so char *ptr =name+3  will be equal to 
  23300+(3*sizeof(char)).so now ptr points to 23300+(3*1)=23303.each element occupies one bye for char so ptr will point to letter 'a' in "dharman".since  "dharman"  is char const you can't its value that's why you are getting error.if u remove the line *ptr=3.the code will work without out any issue.I hope you find this post useful.

Comment: That's the dumbest answer I ever got on SO!